# Execute hosted .JS file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, socket.io

When executing a NodeJS App in the command prompt, you usually do this:

```
node myscript.js
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
node http://www.myhostedsite.com/myscript.js
```

Comment: `curl 'www.myhostedsite.com/myscript.js' | node`? Although I think there are some slight differences between file execution and REPL execution, but I don't remember what they are at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `wget http://www.myhostedsite.com/myscript.js && node myscript.js` to avoid the differences in the REPL (such as `_` being a reference to the last return value, which can break libraries like underscore.js).

You've also tagged socket.io in your question, which implies you might need some dependencies to be available as well. In that case you may need to install those dependencies globally with `npm install -g <dependency name>` in order for the script to run successfully.